# Vimeo : Uncaught Error: The player element passed isn’t a Vimeo embed. at new Player (player.js:2)

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am getting Error while playing this video.

Below is my Code.

```js
  
    var videoWrapperId = '[data-title="cf-vimeo-video"]';
    var videoPlayer = null;
   


    $(function () {
           handleVimeoPlayer()

       
    });

    function handleVimeoPlayer() {
      
        videoFrameSrc = $('iframe', videoWrapperId).attr('src');
        
        $('iframe', videoWrapperId).attr('src', videoFrameSrc);

        videoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player($('iframe', videoWrapperId));
        
        console.log("Log : " , videoPlayer)

        videoPlayer.ready().then(function () {

           
        });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

<div>
            <div data-de-type="video" data-de-editing="false" data-title="cf-vimeo-video" data-ce="false" data-trigger="none" data-animate="fade"
                data-delay="500" data-video-type="vimeo" style="outline: none; cursor: pointer;" aria-disabled="false" data-element-theme="customized"
                data-vimeo-autoplay="yes">

                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/347119375?autoplay=1&muted=1"  frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I run this Code,

I shows me this error.

> Uncaught Error: The player element passed isn’t a Vimeo embed. at new Player (player.js:2)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your `iframe` is lazy-loaded and therefore isn’t ready when you call it.